# Javascript Wildcards with Express

Tags: javascript, regex, express

I am trying to create an app that will get a url using Express. This url is defined in the `?code=` parameter, but I won't know the value of the string after code.

I've tried doing something like this:

```
app.get('?code=' + /(.*)/i, function(req, res) { /* ... */ });
```

And later something like this:

```
app.get(/\?code=(.*)/i, function(req, res) { /* ... */ });
```

But it never matches. I know to use `.*` to match any string via regex, but this isn't how. I was thinking of doing some kind of match expression, but I'm not sure what string to use match on.

Comment: Usually, you would use a path with `app.get()` and then in that handler, you would check the `?code=xxx` parameter and decide what to do based on the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like  you might be misunderstanding what get is expecting. Also, the regex string you are passing is just becoming a string, not doing you much good, but you don't need it anyways.

your app.get syntax should likely be something like this:

```
app.get('/myAwesomeURL/moreURL/:code', function(request, response) {
  var valueForCode = request.params.code;
});
```

but if you are actually only trying to trigger a route based on the presence of the word code, then you can pass straight regex as the first parameter, and test for all kind of things:

```
app.get(/^(?![\w\/\:].*code$)/, function (request, response) {//stuff});
```